# You don't have permission to access /owncloud/ on this server. Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: php, apache, wampserver, owncloud

I'm having a folder named as `owncloud` in my `C:\wamp\www`. I tried to access it through my browser by turning on wamp server and typing `http://localhost/owncloud/` but it shows me this error:

> Forbidden
> You don't have permission to access /owncloud/ on this server.
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80**

you can also see this error in below image:
[image]

Comment: You need to fix the directory permissions. In your current settings, apache server is not allowed to read from the location. Check [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/forbidden-you-don-t-have-permissions-to-access-on-this-server).